# C removing multiple letter from string

Tags: c, string, pointers, while-loop

I input two strings (string1 and string2). What I need to be doing is to remove all the letters FROM string1 that are in string two. EX. string1="abcdefghi", string2="afbdh", output="cegi". Right now it only removes one letter.

I tried to loop *str3 but I think after the first iteration, *str2 is not back to str3[0]

```
void rmstr(char *str2, char *str3)
{
    char *p=str2;

    printf("Old String: %s", str2);

    while(*str2)
    {
       if(*p != *str3)
           *str2++=*p;
       p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. When you push the button labelled `Ask Question`, you are then supposed to ask a question.

Comment: can letters in string1 be repeated?

Comment: @learner, I know that, its just that in the first part of the assignment it was remove one character from the entire string, so now with this question facing me, this is what I have to work with.

Comment: refer to this link http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-characters-from-the-first-string-which-are-present-in-the-second-string/ for your solution.

Comment: Algorithm should be: a) create new empty string b) iterate over all chars in 'string1' and c) add to new string unless they're present in 'string two'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use two pointers, one for reading and one for writing:

```
char *r, *w;

r = w = str1;
while (*r) {
    if (strchr(str3, *r) == NULL) {
      ++w; // advance write pointer
    }
    ++r; // advance read pointer
}
*w = '\0'; // null terminate
```

Alternatively, use an intermediate string which is copied back into `str2` afterwards.

Comment: You didn't perfectly fix my issue. But your code gave me an idea to call my 'rmchr' function in the 'rmstr' function, resulting in the correct output I desire. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

without pointers is here.

Actually there are number of solutions can be possible for this.

One that I have tried is here

```
        string fStr = "bhardwaj", sStr = "dev";
        char[] tStr = new char[fStr.Length];
        int count = -1, j;

        for (j = 0; j < tStr.Length; j++)
            tStr[j] = ' ';
        for (int i = 0; i < fStr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < sStr.Length; j++)
                if (fStr[i] == sStr[j]) break;
            if (j == sStr.Length)
                tStr[++count] = fStr[i];
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like C :)

Comment: its c#, but logic is same for both

Comment: No not the same, I hope you teach me how to `string.Length` in `C`

Comment: for that char array,1) loop through each element, 2)check if that element is !='\0', 3) for every iteration increment a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void rmstr(char *str2, char *str3, char *str4)
{
    char *pch=NULL;
    int i=0,j=0;
    printf("Old String1: %s\n", str2);
    printf("Old String2: %s\n", str3);
    for(j=0;j<strlen(str2);j++)
    {
        char tmp[2] = {str2[j], '\0'};
        pch = strstr(str3, tmp);
        if (pch == NULL)
        {
            str4[i] = str2[j];
            i++;
        }

    }
    str4[i]='\0';
}

int main()
{   
    char str1[] = "abcdefghi";
    char str2[] = "afbdh";
    char str3[256];
    rmstr(str1,str2,str3);
    printf("New string is: %s\n",str3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the code in below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
    char s1[20] = { 0 }, s2[ 20], r[20] = {0}, t[ 26] = { 0};
    int i=0,j=0;

    scanf ("%s",s1);
    scanf ("%s",s2);

    for (i=0; i<strlen (s2); ++i)
    {
        t[s2[i]-'a'] = 1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<strlen (s1); ++i)
    {
        if (!t[s1[i]-'a'])
        {
            r[j]=s1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    r[j]='\0';

    printf ("result:%s\n", r);
}
```

1.Find the characters in s2

2.Compute the resultant string from s1 by excluding the characters of s2.